# I'm running a Python code in Codechef and I can't figure out the error in the second last line of the code. Can someone please spot the error?

Tags: python

Error - Line 9 - else ns>=10:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Code -

```
for _ in (int(input())):
    k=int(input())
    n = int(k/26)
    ns = k - n
    if ns<2:
        print (2**n+" "+0+" "+0)
    elif (ns>=2 and ns<10):
        print (0+" "+2**n+" "+0)    
    else ns>=10:
        print (0+" "+0+" "+2**n)
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full Traceback message.

Comment: Although, of course, ‘else’ should just be ‘else:’. No following expression.

Comment: I'm not able to post the full message because of this - 
"Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon."

Although thanks for the 'else' solution. That was the problem.

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python if syntax", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a condition you want to check for, you need to use elif, else doesn't take any conditions.

```
else:
    print (0+" "+0+" "+2**n)
```

Comment: You're right, it should just be else then! I'll update my answer.

Comment: Oh. Yes. That's it. Thank you so much.  :)